# How to find deadlock threads in python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, deadlock

Does anyone know how to find deadlock threads in python (Django) program?

I know how to do in Java as follows (but don't know in Python):

```
ThreadMXBean bean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
long[] threadIds = bean.findDeadlockedThreads();
if (threadIds != null) {
    ThreadInfo[] infos = bean.getThreadInfo(threadIds);
    ...
```

**EDIT**

I intentionally wrote the following code in views.py of my Django2 application.

```
a_lock = threading.Lock()
b_lock = threading.Lock()
switch_flag = True

def deadlock(request):
    global switch_flag
    if switch_flag:
        with a_lock:
            print("Locked a_lock.")
            switch_flag = False
            sleep(5)
            with b_lock:
                print("Locked a_lock. -> Locked b_lock.")
    else:
        with b_lock:
            print("Locked b_lock.")
            switch_flag = True
            sleep(5)
            with a_lock:
                print("Locked b_lock. -> Locked a_lock.")
```

Version:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.6.3
$ django-admin.py --version
2.0.4
```

Comment: That would depend on how you build your threads and how you manage locks in them.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I edited my question.

Comment: Code that needs a lock or threads is not great for WSGI applications. The same applies to globals and shared module variables. All of them will have nasty side-effects when deployed in a production setup with a WSGI server.

Comment: My goal is not to write correct code but to know how to find deadlock threads in python program. I'm intentionally writing buggy code in [my application](https://github.com/k-tamura/easybuggy4django).

Answer (score 0):

I have written a [small library](https://github.com/pomponchik/locklib) to solve this problem based on [Wait-for Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wait-for_graph).

Download it:

```
$ pip install locklib
```

And use:

```
from threading import Thread
from locklib import SmartLock


lock = SmartLock()
counter = 0

def function():
  global counter

  for _ in range(1000):
      with lock:
          counter += 1

thread_1 = Thread(target=function)
thread_2 = Thread(target=function)
thread_1.start()
thread_2.start()

assert counter == 2000
```

If you try to take a lock that leads to a deadlock, an exception will automatically be raised. This way your code is completely protected from deadlocks.